# Emacs - Specific Linum Customization

Tags: emacs, customization, whitespace, line-numbers

I am trying to apply a few rather specific customizations to Emacs' `linum.el`, using the section from [this EmacsWiki page on Line Numbers](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers) (entitled *Linum: Separating line numbers from text*) as a guide.

I implemented the edit to **linum.el** that adds a space to the right of the line number.  What I am trying to figure out now is how to add an additional space to the left of the line number, so that the line numbers will look something like this:

```
| 1 |#include <stdio.h>  (Vertical bars for visualization)
| 2 |int main()
```

Another customization I am trying to accomplish involves including the right space in coloring the background for the line numbers. When I set the background for the **linum** face, it doesn't color that new space on the right of the line number.

To illustrate, here is how the **linum** background covers currently:

```
(current) |1| #!/bin/bash   -- vs. -->   |1 |#!/bin/bash (ideal)
          |2| echo "123"    --------->   |2 |echo "123"
```

I did attempt to implement the former (space-on-left) by blindly tinkering with the line from the EmacsWiki that gives the right space, to no success.  Unfortunately, since I am somewhat new to Emacs and Elisp, my skills aren't at the level yet where I can spot what I need to change easily on my own.

---

**Links:**

EmacsWiki: Line Numbers [Section - *Linum: Separating line numbers from text*]

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do it like you said, using spaces, and not as @lawlist suggested, find the line containing `(number-to-string w)` in function `linum-update-window` and change it to:

```
(number-to-string (+ w 1))
```

This number is the width of the box in which the line number is printed, right aligned.
The original `w` is the number of digits in the last line number.

Comment: I have a space to the left now!
I'll probably figure out how to get the whole thing included as the background, but you answered my main question. Thanks!

Comment: I added a space after the "d" in `(concat "%" (number-to-string (+ w 1)) "d")`, the same line you mention, and it puts a space on the right that is included with the bg color!  Both solved now!  Thanks again

Comment: Well, yes, I didn't say anything about that because it had already been answered on the EmacsWiki (although in a different way from the one you found).  Playing with this format string you can do all sorts of things with the line number.  Change `d` to `x` and you'll get them in hexadecimal!

Answer (score 15):

I believe setting `(setq linum-format "%d ")` will do what you want. If you also want the space in the left, use `" %d "` for the format.

Comment: Yes, there's absolutely no need to go editing the linum library.

Comment: When I don't use a background for the linum face, this looks like it works and is much easier than editing the linum.el file.  When I do use a background, it's uneven between single and double digits.

Comment: @mellowmaroon: I don't really know. Emacs will use whatever the columns needed to display the highest line number. Files that have 1-9 lines: 1 columns, 10 - 99 lines: 2 columns .etc. If you want to have at least a fixed number of columns, you can use `" %4d "`. I normally use `" %3d "` as I think files with >= 1k lines should be refactored.

Answer (score 3):

Does something like this give you any ideas on your own type of customization?  You may be more interested in setting the fringe width, instead of altering spaces to the right of the line numbers.

```
(setq-default left-fringe-width  10)
(setq-default right-fringe-width  0)
(set-face-attribute 'fringe nil :background "white" :foreground "white")


;;    (setq linum-format "%d") ;; alternative solution to intermittent line numbers
(custom-set-faces '(linum ((t (:foreground "pink" :background "white" :box nil)))) ) 
(eval-after-load 'linum
  '(progn
     (defface linum-leading-zero
       `((t :inherit 'linum
            :foreground ,(face-attribute 'linum :background nil t)))
       "Face for displaying leading zeroes for line numbers in display margin."
       :group 'linum)
     (defun linum-format-func (line)
       (let ((w (length
                 (number-to-string (count-lines (point-min) (point-max))))))
         (concat
;;        (propertize (make-string (- w (length (number-to-string line))) ?0)
          (propertize (make-string (- w (length (number-to-string line))) ? ) ;; change leading zero to a soft space
                      'face 'linum-leading-zero)
          (propertize (number-to-string line) 'face 'linum))))
     (setq linum-format 'linum-format-func)))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fringe width"?  The space for line numbers?

Comment: There is a vertical line to the right of the line numbers that can be changed in color and thickness -- it is called a fringe.  The first 3 lines of code control that behavior -- except the right fringe, which is of course the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easier solution is just to fix the size of the `linum` face attribute, with something like:

```
(set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height 140)
```

You may need to hook this up after you actually *use* the `linum-mode`:

```
(defun fix-linum-size ()
  (interactive)  
  (set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height 140))

(add-hook 'linum-mode-hook 'fix-linum-size)
```